# installing homebank with brew

Tags: macos, install, homebrew

while installing homebank software I am getting error

> Error: You must `brew link intltool xz' before homebank can be
>   installed

```
MacBook-Pro:/ Sarfaraz$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null

MacBook-Pro:/ Sarfaraz$ brew install homebank
==> Installing dependencies for homebank: pkg-config, intltool, xz, gettext, libffi, glib, jpeg, libtiff, libpng, gobject-introspection, gdk-pixbuf, atk,
==> Installing homebank dependency: pkg-config
==> Downloading http://pkgconfig.freedesktop.org/releases/pkg-config-0.28.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.28 --disable-host-tool --with-internal-glib --with-pc-path=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkg
==> make
==> make check
==> make install
  /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.28: 10 files, 600K, built in 2.9 minutes
==> Installing homebank dependency: intltool
==> Downloading https://launchpad.net/intltool/trunk/0.51.0/+download/intltool-0.51.0.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/intltool/0.51.0 --disable-silent-rules
==> make install
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/man/man8/intltool-extract.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8 is not writable.

You can try again using:
  brew link intltool
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/intltool/0.51.0: 19 files, 224K, built in 16 seconds
==> Installing homebank dependency: xz
==> Downloading https://fossies.org/linux/misc/xz-5.2.1.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --disable-silent-rules --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.1
==> make install
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink lib/pkgconfig/liblzma.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig is not writable.

You can try again using:
  brew link xz
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.1: 59 files, 1.6M, built in 117 seconds
==> Installing homebank dependency: gettext
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gettext/gettext-0.19.4.tar.xz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --disable-silent-rules --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.4 --with-included-gettext --with-included-glib --with-included-libcroco --with-in
==> make
==> make install
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

Mac OS X provides similar software, and installing this software in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

OS X provides the BSD gettext library and some software gets confused if both are in the library path.

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.4: 1920 files, 21M, built in 13.3 minutes
==> Installing homebank dependency: libffi
==> Downloading http://mirrors.kernel.org/sources.redhat.com/libffi/libffi-3.0.13.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.0.13
==> make install
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

Mac OS X already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

Some formulae require a newer version of libffi.

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.0.13: 14 files, 408K, built in 52 seconds
==> Installing homebank dependency: glib
==> Downloading http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.44/glib-2.44.0.tar.xz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jacknagel/af332f42fae80c570a77/raw/7b5fd0d2e6554e9b770729fddacaa2d648327644/glib-hardcoded-paths.diff

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "glib--patch"
Download failed: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jacknagel/af332f42fae80c570a77/raw/7b5fd0d2e6554e9b770729fddacaa2d648327644/glib-hardcoded-paths.diff

Imheres-MacBook-Pro:imhereV1 Sarfaraz$ brew install homebank
Error: You must `brew link intltool xz' before homebank can be installed

Imheres-MacBook-Pro:imhereV1 Sarfaraz$ brew link intltool xz
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/intltool/0.51.0... 
Error: Could not symlink share/man/man8/intltool-extract.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8 is not writable.
```

Comment: What does `brew doctor` say?

Comment: `brew doctor` is there to fix issues like these.

Answer (score 6):

**brew doctor**

The `brew doctor` command is designed to fix issues like this. Just follow the instructions in your terminal after running the command.

Answer (score 5):

After upgrading to El Capitan, `/usr/local` permissions are changed to root. For Homebrew to work you need to do this:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

Comment: doing this solved the problem but now I am getting error 'curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "glib--patch"
Download failed: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jacknagel/af332f42fae80c570a77/raw/7b5fd0d2e6554e9b770729fddacaa2d648327644/glib-hardcoded-paths.diff' when I did 'brew install homebank'

Comment: @Saifee, could you try uninstalling and re-installing `homebank`. it installed fine for me just now.

Comment: @Saifee, If not, I suggest creating a new post with all errors in detail along with output of `brew doctor`

Answer (score 1):

After seeing this several times in your output
`/usr/local/share/man/man8 is not writable.`

I'm going to have to suggest doing this and then try again:
`sudo chown $(whoami):admin /usr/local/share/man/man8`

Comment: This error is also there `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig is not writable.`

Comment: Just run `brew docter`. That will fix all issues.